# ggplot: Why do I have to transform the data into the long format?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

When plotting with ggplot, I often have to transforme the data into the long format, for example, like in the code below. Two questions arise for me:

1. Is there a way to use the column (so each variable) as a "group"? So each column is plotted and has a different color? Hence it would not be necessary to transform the data to the long format. (Without putting every variable into a `geom_line()`)
2. Why is it the case that you have to transform the data into the long format? What is the reason behind it? How is it better than plotting when your data has the wide format?

The example code:

```
library(tidyverse) 
# Data in wide format
  df_wide <- data.frame(
   Horizons = seq(1,10,1),
   Country1 = c(2.5, 2.3, 2.2, 2.2, 2.1, 2.0, 1.7, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6),
   Country2 = c(3.5, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 3.0, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7, 3.6),
   Country3 = c(1.5, 1.3, 1.2, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6)
   )

# Convert to long format
  df_long <- df_wide %>%
   gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -Horizons)
    
# Plot the lines
  plotstov <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Horizons, y = value)) + 
   geom_line(aes(colour = variable, group = variable))+
   theme_bw()
```

Output:
[image: output]
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You would have to add each variable separated in a different geom_line, is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I know that this is the case. But is there not option to do it automatically? Like when you have the data in long format?

Comment: I believe that is the reason why tidyverse functions exist, but you can connect the pivot with the plot directly in the pipeline to avoid creating a separated object and then plot it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to be say for sure that this is impossible — for example, someone could write a wrapper package for `ggplot` that would do this automatically for you — but there's no obvious solution like this.

Hadley Wickham, the author of `ggplot`, has built the entire "tidyverse" ecosystem on the concept of [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html), which is essentially data in long format.  The basic reason for working with long-format data is that the same data can be represented by many wide formats, but the long format is typically unique. For example, suppose you have data representing revenues by year, country, and industrial sector. In a wide format, do columns represent year, country, sector, or some combination?  In the tidyverse/ggplot world, you can simply specify which variable you want to use as the grouping variable. With a wide-format-oriented tool (such as base R's `matplot`), you would first reshape your data so that the columns represented the grouping variable (say, years), then plot it.

Wickham and co-workers built tools like `gather` (or `pivot_longer` in newer versions of the tidyverse) to make conversion to long format easy, and a wide variety of other tools to work with long ("tidy") data.

You could write wrappers around `ggplot` that would do the conversion ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Finally I have closure with this question :) I always thought it maybe had some other reasons

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, you already have the answer to your second question, so I'll focus here on the first question.

Answer 2 - Yes, there is a way to plot each column separately, specifying them as follows:

```
# load environment
library(ggplot2)
# create dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  Horizons = seq(1,10,1),
  Country1 = c(2.5, 2.3, 2.2, 2.2, 2.1, 2.0, 1.7, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6),
  Country2 = c(3.5, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 3.0, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7, 3.6),
  Country3 = c(1.5, 1.3, 1.2, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6)
)
# plot
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Horizons, y = Country1, colour = 'Country1')) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Horizons, y = Country2, colour = 'Country2')) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Horizons, y = Country3, colour = 'Country3'))
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, you have to specify each column, which may cause problems when you have a large dataset. As experienced by me, it's much harder to define which will be the colour of each line, since `scale_colour_manual()` gets confused when the dataset is not structured in a long format with a column describing the label/colour of each row.

It may be useful to use a wide format sometimes, but I advise you to always use the long format. You will make a smarter use of **tidyverse** packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I knew this already. I wanted to know if there is a way without putting every variable in `geom_line`. I was not clear enough in my question, that this is not what I wanted, my bad. But thanks a lot for the awnser anyway.