# Take multiple values from dataframe for complex ggplot/dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe.
[image]

And I want to make something similar to this:

[image]

What I managed to do so far is just using one column against (Q1) against sex (Genul).
But I want to include every question/column in the plot.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x = Q1, y = 1, colour = Genul)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1), linetype = "dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: The typical approach for this kind of ggplot2 question is to reshape your data into longer format before ggplot, eg. by using `tidyr::pivot_longer(-Genul)`

Comment: Why would you do that? And what next?

Comment: Because ggplot2 works best with long format (also called 'tidy') data. Your data is in a wide format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fundamental "issue" in this question is summed up by [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839732/take-multiple-values-from-dataframe-for-complex-ggplot-dotplot#comment118149743_66839732) *"Why would you do that?"*. Through it all, `ggplot2` can do so much more (and more easily) when the data is in a long format vice wide. With that, I suggest you read [ggplot: Why do I have to transform the data into the long format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64390747/3358272), which provides two answers to address the question.

To close out your question of how to replicate that picture, here's some random data and a plot that gets you further along the path.

```r
questions <- data.frame(
  qnum = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"),
  qtxt = c("More intense room cleaning", "Conduct COVID-19 rapid tests",
           "Additional cleaning")
)

set.seed(42)
responses <- cbind(
  data.frame(Genul = c("Feminin", "Masculin")),
  sapply(c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"),
         function(ign) runif(n = 2, min = 0, max = 50),
         simplify = FALSE)
)

responses
#      Genul       Q1       Q2       Q3
# 1  Feminin 45.74030 14.30698 32.08728
# 2 Masculin 46.85377 41.52238 25.95480
```

Here's what the reshaped data looks like:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
pivot_longer(responses, -Genul, names_to = "qnum")
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Genul    qnum  value
#   <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
# 1 Feminin  Q1     45.7
# 2 Feminin  Q2     14.3
# 3 Feminin  Q3     32.1
# 4 Masculin Q1     46.9
# 5 Masculin Q2     41.5
# 6 Masculin Q3     26.0
```

And here's the plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
responses %>%
  pivot_longer(-Genul, names_to = "qnum") %>%
  left_join(questions, by = "qnum") %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, qtxt)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Genul)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 50))
```

[image: sample ggplot]

You seem to have some theme changes not present in your code, I'm confident they'll apply is cleanly to this approach. Your questions might need some adjusting to fit them more cleanly; for that, I suggest perhaps a combination of `strwrap` and `paste(.., collapse="\n")` for each one ... a different question, and it may not be necessary depending on your actual data.

(Another note: you might need to use `factor`s on your questions to ensure they are ordered correctly. This factoring should likely happen in my `questions` frame, ordered on `qnum`.)